# Make a new array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, header, sequence

I am writing a program that parses sequence alleles. I have written code that reads a file and creates a header array and a sequence array. Here is an example of a file:

```
>DQB1*04:02:01
------------------------------------------------------------
--ATGTCTTGGAAGAAGGCTTTGCGGAT-------CCCTGGAGGCCTTCGGGTAGCAACT
GTGACCTT----GATGCTGGCGATGCTGAGCACCCCGGTGGCTGAGGGCAGAGACTCTCC
CGAGGATTTCGTGTTCCAGTTTAAGGGCATGTGCTACTTCACCAACGGGACCGAGCGCGT
GTTGGAGCTCCGCACGACCTTGCAGCGGCGA-----------------------------
---GTGGAGCCCACAGTGACCATCTCCCCATCCAGGACAGAGGCCCTCAACCACCACAAC
CTGCTGGTCTGCTCAGTGACAG----CATTGGAGGCTTCGTGCTGGGGCTGATCTTCCTC
GGGCTGGGCCTTATTATC--------------CATCACAGGAGTCAGAAAGGGCTCCTGC
ACTGA-------------------------------------------------------
>OMIXON_CONSENSUS_M_155_09_4890_DQB1*04:02:01
-------------------ATCAGGTCCAAGCTGTGTTGACTACCACTACTTTTCCCTTC
GTCTCAATTATGTCTTGGAAGAAGGCTTTGCGGATCCCTGGAGGCCTTCGGGTAGCAACT
GTGACCTTGATGCTGGCGATGCTGAGCACCCCGGTGGCTGAGGGCAGAGACTCTCCCGGT
AAGTGCAGGGCCACTGCTCTCCAGAGCCGCCACTCTGGGAACAGGCTCTCCTTGGGCTGG
GGTAGGGGGATGGTGATCTCCATGATCTCGGACACAATCTTTCATCAACATTTCCTCTCT
TTGGGGAAAGAGAACGATGTTGCATTCCCATTTATCTTT---------------------
>GENDX_CONSENSUS_M_155_09_4890_DQB1*04:02:01
TGCCAGGTACATCAGATCCATCAGGTCCAAGCTGTGTTGACTACCACTACTTTTCCCTTC
GTCTCAATTATGTCTTGGAAGAAGGCTTTGCGGATCCCTGGAGGCCTTCGGGTAGCAACT
GTGACCTTGATGCTGGCGATGCTGAGCACCCCGGTGGCTGAGGGCAGAGACTCTCCCGGT
AAGTGCAGGGCCACTGCTCTCCAGAGCCGCCACTCTGGGAACAGGCTCTCCTTGGGCTGG
GGTAGGGGGATGGTGATCTCCATGATCTCGGACACAATCTTTCATCAACATTTCCTCTCT
```

The headers are ('>DQB1', '>GENDX', and '>OMIXON') and the three sequences are the other three strings as seen above.

The next part of my code detects if the allele sequence is complete or incomplete. An allele is determined as "incomplete" if there are more than 4 breaks within the >DQB1 sequence. (A break is signified by a '-'). For example, the above sequence is broken because there are five breaks.

I am trying to write code where if there is an incomplete allele detected, the program creates a new array with only the >GENDX and the >OMIXON headers and sequences.

How can I make an array that does not include >DQB1?

Here is my code as is:

```
import sys, re

max_num_breaks=4
filename=sys.argv[1]
f=open(filename,"r")
header=[]
header2=[]
sequence=[]
sequence2=[]
string=""
for line in f:
    if ">" in line and string=="":
        header.append(line[:-1])
    elif ">" in line and string!="":
        sequence.append(string)
        header.append(line[:-1])
        string=""
    else:
        string=string+line[:-1]
sequence.append(string)
s1=sequence[0]
breaks=sum(1 for m in re.finditer("-+",''.join(s1.splitlines())))
if breaks>max_num_breaks:
    print "Incomplete Reference Allele Detected"
    for m in range(len(header)):
        if re.finditer(header[m], 'OMIXON') or re.finditer(header[m], 'GENDX'):
            header2.append(header[m])
            sequence2.append(sequence[m])
    print header2
```

The problem with the above code is that whenever I print header2 it still includes the DQB1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to use `re.finditer`?

What about

```
if header[m].find('OMIXON') > -1 or header[m].find('GENDX') > -1:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily using [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython), assuming your sequences are saved in a FASTA file.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

headers = [record.id for record in SeqIO.parse("myfile.fasta", "fasta")][1:]
```

and you're done.

If you want to get the sequence part from the `parse()` object, just use `record.seq`.

Comment: I originally wrote the code with biopython and it was having a lot of problems so I figured out how to do it without.

Comment: @GiaConstantina what problems were you having?

Comment: I don't think it downloaded properly bc in general it would not let me access things like SeqIO and other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The re.finditer function does not do what you think it does. For an example, see [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/10/python-finditer-regular-expression/).

I would recommend using this instead:

```
if header[m][1:7] == 'OMIXON' or header[m][1:6]=='GENDX':
```